# Editing multiple elements in Android XML layout via Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, properties

I am trying to edit multiple textview's in a xml layout. Before installing Juno, i was selecting multiple elements pressing shift button and all properties were shown on the Properties view, so i can make batch edits. Now all i have on Properties View;
**ID,
Text,
Hint,
Text Color,
Text Appereance,
Text Size,
Content**
In this particular case i want to change all their gravities from none to right. I guess i did something wrong with the eclipse preferences or missing something else.. need help thx

Comment: i think you could try to make the preferences to default :D

Comment: I havent really changed anything, its like this out of the box. I just need someone to confirm if anyone using the same shift select method in the latest Juno+Android Sdk+Eclipse ADT Plugin...

Comment: I just found a solution to be able to do it.
Selecting all elements from the xml layout, right click->Other Properties->Defined By TextView->Gravity lets you to change them all. But still my question now is how can i let the properties view to show all these attributes defined by all possible types..

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with Eclipse 4.2.1. I opened an xml layout file, selected a bunch of TextViews, then did a right click and clicked "Properties". All attributes appeared in the properties view and I easily batch-edited them.